# How to set current Navbar Link to Active-Color in Laravel without using blade

Tags: laravel

i'm new to laravel. I need to set current Navbar Link to Active-Color in Laravel without using blade

i'm try when i use blade :- `{{(request()->is('label')) ? 'active' : '' }}`

but i need active class without using laravel blad ?

Code where i add Active class :-

```
 $str .= '<li class="loader-visible" id="id'.$favObj->artist_id.'">';
```

i try :-

```
$str .= '<li class="loader-visible '.request()->is("label") ? "active" : "" .'" id="id'.$favObj->artist_id.'">';
```

But Not Working

Comment: Why not using blade ? You can still use regular PHP... `<?php echo request()->is('label') ? 'active' : '';  ?>`

Comment: beacuse i'm use in controller @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: This is not working @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: Well, the controller is not meant for that. I think we will need a minimal and reproducible code to understand how we can help you.

Comment: Check i add my code @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: Can you confirm, the URL you access this controller is: `your-url.test/label` or `127.0.0.1:8000/label`

Comment: No not access the controller @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: This is normal then. When the condition applies it will test if your url is `/label`, so when you hit this controller with an anther url, the condition will be false and won't add the class.